# How do I continue tic-tac-toe game from saved yaml file?

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml, dump

I have the following tic-tac-toe game: (I'm a noob, please disregard the design of the class, the game works, that's all I care about for now.)

```
#a tic tac toe game
class TicTacToe
    require "yaml"
    attr_accessor :player1, :player2
    #crates playes and a game board to play tic tac toe
    def initialize()
        @player1 = Player.new("Player One", "x")
        @player2 = Player.new("Player Two", "o")
        @game_board = Board.new
    end

    #prints the board
    def print_board
        @game_board.board.each_with_index do |row, index| 
            puts "#{row.join(" | ")}"
            puts "---------" unless index == 2
        end
        puts
    end

    #determines whose move it is
    def move
        if @turn % 2 == 1
            player_one_turn
        else
            player_two_turn
        end
        @turn += 1
    end

    def valid_move?(row, col)
        if @game_board.board[row][col] == " "
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    #player ones turn
    def player_one_turn
        print_board
        puts "#{@player1.name} it's your turn:"
        puts "Enter a row (0-2)"
        row = gets.chomp.to_i
        puts "Enter a column (0-2)"
        col = gets.chomp.to_i
        if valid_move?(row, col)
            @game_board.board[row][col] = @player1.shape
        else
            puts "There's already a shape at that position."
            player_one_turn
        end

        if win?(@player1.shape)
            winner(@player1.name)
            @winner = true
        end
    end

    #player two's turn
    def player_two_turn
        print_board
        puts "#{@player2.name} it's your turn:"
        puts "Enter a row (0-2)"
        row = gets.chomp.to_i
        puts "Enter a column (0-2)"
        col = gets.chomp.to_i
        if valid_move?(row, col)
            @game_board.board[row][col] = @player2.shape
        else
            puts "There's already a shape at that position."
            player_two_turn
        end

        if win?(@player2.shape)
            winner(@player2.name)
            @winner = true
        end
    end

    def win?(shape)
        if (@game_board.board[0][0] == shape) && (@game_board.board[0][1] == shape) && (@game_board.board[0][2] == shape)
            return true
        elsif (@game_board.board[1][0] == shape) && (@game_board.board[1][1] == shape) && (@game_board.board[1][2] == shape)
            return true
        elsif (@game_board.board[2][0] == shape) && (@game_board.board[2][1] == shape) && (@game_board.board[2][2] == shape)
            return true
        elsif (@game_board.board[0][0] == shape) && (@game_board.board[1][0] == shape) && (@game_board.board[2][0] == shape)
            return true
        elsif (@game_board.board[0][1] == shape) && (@game_board.board[1][1] == shape) && (@game_board.board[2][1] == shape)
            return true
        elsif (@game_board.board[0][2] == shape) && (@game_board.board[1][2] == shape) && (@game_board.board[2][2] == shape)
            return true
        elsif (@game_board.board[0][0] == shape) && (@game_board.board[1][1] == shape) && (@game_board.board[2][2] == shape)
            return true
        elsif (@game_board.board[0][2] == shape) && (@game_board.board[1][1] == shape) && (@game_board.board[2][0] == shape)
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    def draw?
        if @turn > 9
            print_board
            puts "The game ended in a draw. :)"
            @winner = true
            return true
        end
        false
    end

    def winner(winner_name)
        puts "#{winner_name}, YOU WIN!!!"
    end

    def play
        @turn = 1
        @winner = false

        until @winner
            move unless draw?
            save
        end
    end


    #a class that generates an empty board
    class Board
    attr_accessor :board
        def initialize
            @board = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
        end
    end

    #a class that assigns creates plaers and assigns them a shape "x" or "o"
    class Player
        attr_accessor :name, :shape
        def initialize(name, shape)
            @name = name
            @shape = shape
        end
    end

    def save
        yaml = YAML::dump(self)
        File.open("save.txt", "w"){|file| file.write(yaml)}
    end

    def self.load
        file = File.read("save.txt")
        YAML::load_file(file)
    end
end

game = TicTacToe.new
game.play
```

I want to start playing the game, quit the program in the middle of the game and then come back and finish it later after I call `TicTacToe.load`. However, when I do this now, the YAML file is loaded, but program does not resume where it's supposed to.

Can someone tell me if there is a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You have shown a lot of code, including `.save` and `.load` method definitions for the board (critically, you don't have anything which stores other game state, such as whose turn it is, which may be a clue as to what you are missing). However, I cannot see anywhere in the code that you actually use those methods, or how you are attempting to quit, save, then load and re-start the game. You need to show that code - even if it is just trying something in IRB - because otherwise it is anyone's guess on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regionally thought that doing something like `YAML::load(self)` would automatically load the save state of the file I was referring to via some kind of magic. However, I have come to learn that that the way that I designed my class and the dependencies in my "play" function would not allow me to load the previous state if my file.

When loading a YAML file, one has to load the file to a variable and then manually assign the object values to values of the class. That way, the current state of the variables are pretty much being manually assigned to the instance variables of the class. For example, I could have done something like this: `file = YAML.load("file_name")`, then assign variables values like: `@board = file.board`.

Had I known this before, I would have designed my class with less dependencies so that it would be loadable in a much cleaner and more convenient way.